# Best practice for storing DateTime as string in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Let's say I MUST store a `DateTime` value as `string` in SQL Server in my web application. This web app will be deployed to multiple servers behind a LB and share the same DB server.

This is a legacy project and apparently the guys developed it simply called `ToString()` on the `DateTime` instance, and this will format the datetime according to the culture setting of the machine; and when retrieving the datetime, a simple `DateTime.Parse()` would parse it correctly with the same culture setting implicitly.

However I do not believe this is a good approach, as this creates a dependency between the data and the culture setting of the machine, it means if **multiple** devs have **different** timezone settings they will be inserting the `DateTime` in different formats and this will error later when these values are parsed back to `DateTime`.

I think a better approach would be to define a unified **standard** of the format of `DateTime` (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy), so that the data can work across different machines. However I'd like to know if there is any downside or unexpected issues with this approach and would greatly appreciate your insight!

Comment: I'd store the DateTime as a `DateTimeOffset`, and then create a computed column in the table that automatically returned the proper string representation.  Using `DateTimeOffset` preserves TimeZone info, in case your devs are in different zones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best format for storing a date/time as a string is an ISO 8601 standard format, either YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD (I prefer the version with the hyphens because I am a human being).

This format is standard, almost completely unambiguous (YYYYDDMM is almost unknown as a format).  It also sorts correctly and can be used for `between`-type comparisons.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that makes so much sense!! :)

Comment: "because I am a human being"  ... All evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . LOL, but you don't know me.